# C++ - What would happen if two library uses same source code for build

Tags: c++, design-patterns, shared-libraries, token-name-resolution

I have doubt is it possible if  I built `lib1.so` using source file `common.cpp`and `lib2.so` using same source file `common.cpp` again. Now I want to build my application `APP` using this two library ,

My question are

1. is it possible Or it will give me error ?
2. If it will successfully built then how naming gets resolved? 
   F.e. let say `foo` is class in `common.cpp`. `foo_v1` is object of foo in lib1.so and `foo_v2` is object of foo in lib2.so. Now during bulid of `APP` what would happen? Also is it possible to create object of foo in `APP` application ?

Comment: Why would you like to do this? The best practice would be to create a lib3.so, which includes the `common.cpp`  logic and link both libraries and the `APP` against it.

Comment: You can build both dynamic libraries without problems. You should not get any name resolution errors as long as the common functions are not exported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Naturally one would suggest you consider building the common functionality shared
by `lib1.so` and `lib2.so` into a distinct shared library, `libcommon.so`.

But if you want nevertheless to statically link the common functionality
identically<sup>1</sup>
into both `lib1.so` and `lib2.so`, you can link these two shared libraries with
your program. The linker will have no problem with that. Here is an
illustration:

**common.h**

```
#ifndef COMMON_H
#define COMMON_H
#include <string>

struct common
{
    void print1(std::string const & s) const;
    void print2(std::string const & s) const;
    static unsigned count;
};
```

**common.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "common.h"

unsigned common::count = 0;

void common::print1(std::string const & s) const
{
    std::cout << s << ". (count = " << count++ << ")" << std::endl;
}

void common::print2(std::string const & s) const
{
    std::cout << s << ". (count = " << count++ << ")" << std::endl;
}
```

**foo.h**

```
#ifndef FOO_H
#define FOO_H
#include "common.h"

struct foo
{
    void i_am() const;
private:
    common _c;
};

#endif
```

**foo.cpp**

```
#include "foo.h"

void foo::i_am() const
{
    _c.print1(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
}
```

**bar.h**

```
#ifndef BAR_H
#define BAR_H
#include "common.h"

struct bar
{
    void i_am() const;
private:
    common _c;
};

#endif
```

**bar.cpp**

```
#include "bar.h"

void bar::i_am() const
{
    _c.print2(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
}
```

Now we'll make two shared libraries, `libfoo.so` and `libbar.so`. The
source files we need are `foo.cpp`, `bar.cpp` and `common.cpp`. First
compile them all to [PIC (Position Independent Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position-independent_code)
object files:

```
$ g++ -Wall -Wextra -fPIC -c foo.cpp bar.cpp common.cpp
```

And here are the object files we just made:

```
$ ls *.o
bar.o  common.o  foo.o
```

Now link `libfoo.so` using `foo.o` and `common.o`:

```
$ g++ -shared -o libfoo.so foo.o common.o
```

Then link `libbar.so` using `bar.o` and (again) `common.o`

```
$ g++ -shared -o libbar.so bar.o common.o
```

We can see that `common::...` symbols are *defined* and exported by `libfoo.so`:

```
$ nm -DC libfoo.so | grep common
0000000000202094 B common::count
0000000000000e7e T common::print1(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) const
0000000000000efa T common::print2(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) const
```

(`T` means *defined in the code section*, `B` means *defined in the uinitialized data section*). And exactly the same is true about `libbar.so`

```
$ nm -DC libbar.so | grep common
0000000000202094 B common::count
0000000000000e7e T common::print1(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) const
0000000000000efa T common::print2(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) const
```

Now we'll make a program linked with these libraries:

**main.cpp**

```
#include "foo.h"
#include "bar.h"

int main()
{
    foo f;
    bar b;
    common c;

    f.i_am();
    b.i_am();
    c.print1(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    return 0;
}
```

It calls `foo`; it calls `bar`,
and it calls `common::print1`.

```
$ g++ -Wall -Wextra -c main.cpp
$ g++ -o prog main.o -L. -lfoo -lbar -Wl,-rpath=$PWD
```

It runs like:

```
$ ./prog
void foo::i_am() const. (count = 0)
void bar::i_am() const. (count = 1)
int main(). (count = 2)
```

Which is just fine. You might perhaps have worried that *two copies* of the static class variable
`common::count` would end up in the program - one from `libfoo.so` and another from `libbar.so`,
and that `foo` would increment one copy and `bar` would increment the other. But that didn't happen.

How did the linker resolve the `common::...` symbols? Well to see that we need to find their mangled forms,
as the linker sees them:

```
$ nm common.o | grep common
0000000000000140 t _GLOBAL__sub_I_common.cpp
0000000000000000 B _ZN6common5countE
0000000000000000 T _ZNK6common6print1ERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE
000000000000007c T _ZNK6common6print2ERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE
```

There they all are and we can tell which one is which with `c++filt`:

```
$ c++filt _ZN6common5countE
common::count

$ c++filt _ZNK6common6print1ERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE
common::print1(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) const

$ c++filt _ZNK6common6print2ERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE
common::print2(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) const
```

Now we can re-do the linkage of `prog`, this time asking the linker to tell us the names of the
input files in which these `common::...` symbols were defined or referenced. This diagnostic
linkage is a bit of a mouthful, so I'll `\`-split it:

```
$ g++ -o prog main.o -L. -lfoo -lbar -Wl,-rpath=$PWD \
    -Wl,-trace-symbol=_ZN6common5countE \
    -Wl,-trace-symbol=_ZNK6common6print1ERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE \
    -Wl,-trace-symbol=_ZNK6common6print2ERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE        
main.o: reference to _ZNK6common6print1ERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE
./libfoo.so: definition of _ZN6common5countE
./libfoo.so: definition of _ZNK6common6print2ERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE
./libfoo.so: definition of _ZNK6common6print1ERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE
./libbar.so: reference to _ZN6common5countE
./libbar.so: reference to _ZNK6common6print2ERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE
./libbar.so: reference to _ZNK6common6print1ERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE
```

So the linker tells us that it linked the definition of `common::count` from `./libfoo.so`. Likewise the
definition of `common::print1`. Likewise the definition of `common::print2`. It linked *all* the
`common::...` symbol definitions from `libfoo.so`.

It tells us that the reference(s) to `common::print1` in `main.o` was resolved to the definition in `libfoo.so`. Likewise
the reference(s) to `common::count` in `libbar.so`. Likewise the reference(s) to `common::print1` and
`common::print2` in `libbar.so`. *All* the `common::...` symbol references in the program were resolved to the
definitions provided by `libfoo.so`.

So there were no *multiple definition* errors, and there is no uncertainty about which "copies" or "versions" of the `common::...` symbols are used
by the program: it just uses the definitions from `libfoo.so`.

Why? Simply because `libfoo.so` was the *first* library in the linkage that provided definitions
for the `common::...`symbols. If we relink `prog` with the order of `-lfoo` and `-lbar` reversed:

```
$ g++ -o prog main.o -L. -lbar -lfoo -Wl,-rpath=$PWD \
    -Wl,-trace-symbol=_ZN6common5countE \
    -Wl,-trace-symbol=_ZNK6common6print1ERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE \
    -Wl,-trace-symbol=_ZNK6common6print2ERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE        
main.o: reference to _ZNK6common6print1ERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE
./libbar.so: definition of _ZN6common5countE
./libbar.so: definition of _ZNK6common6print2ERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE
./libbar.so: definition of _ZNK6common6print1ERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE
./libfoo.so: reference to _ZN6common5countE
./libfoo.so: reference to _ZNK6common6print2ERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE
./libfoo.so: reference to _ZNK6common6print1ERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE
```

then we get exactly the opposite answers. *All* the `common::...` symbol references in the program
are now resolved to the definitions provided by `libbar.so`. Because `libbar.so` provided them *first*.
There is still no uncertainty, and it makes no difference to the program, because both `libfoo.so`
and `libbar.so` linked the `common::...` definitions from the same object file, `common.o`.

The linker does not *try* to find multiple definitions of symbols. Once it has found a
definition of a symbol *S*, in an input object file or shared library, it binds references to
*S* to the definition it has found and is done with resolving *S*. It does
not care if a shared library it finds later can provide another definition of *S*, the same or different,
even if that later shared library resolves symbols *other* than *S*.

The only way in which you can cause a multiple definition error is by compelling the linker
to *statically link* multiple definitions, i.e. compel it to physically merge into the output binary
two *object files* `obj1.o` and `obj2.o` both of which contain a definition *S*.
If you do that, the competing static definitions have exactly the same status, and only
one definition can be used by the program, so the linker has to fail you. But it does not need to take any notice of a
dynamic symbol definition of *S* provided by a shared library *if it has already resolved S*, and it does not do so.

---

[1] Of course, if you compile and link `lib1` and `lib2` with different preprocessor, compiler or linkage options, you can sabotage the "common" functionality to an arbitary extent.

Comment: Understood everything , except the last part of different preprocessor etc.

Comment: @arunpal Hi. Well if I compiled everything with `-Dcommon=uncommon` for my `libfoo` but not `libbar`, then there would be no `common::` symbols in both libraries. Or I could use linker option `--defsym` to change the names of symbols in `libbar` but not `libfoo`. So [1] means you don't modify the source or object code differently for the two libraries.